# make url semantic (dynamic) in Flask

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I build a simple flusk service, this is a part of home page:

```
           <form action="/results" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <label class="required">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="required">ID: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="ID" name="ID" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" onclick="loading()"> Submit </button>
        </form>
```

Here is a part of python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
  def main_page():
    return render_template('ui/home_page.html')

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
  def show_results():
    # do something...
    return render_template('ui/result_page.html')
```

It works when I click button and shows results in *http://localhost:8080/results*.

I now want to make the result url to be semantic base on users' input in the home page such as *http://localhost:8080/results/user=balabala&ID=balabala*. I tried modify the python

```
@app.route('/results/<url_postfix>', methods=['POST'])
  def process_diff_by_platform(url_postfix):
    # do something...
    return render_template('ui/result_page.html')
```

but it shows 404 Not Found. I guess this is because that I hard coded the url in html template. But I have no idea how to fix that...
How do I solve this problem?

~ thanks

Comment: I suppose you wont get the`<url_postfix>` since the method is `POST`

Comment: you can have url `results?name=balabala&ID=balabala` (with `?`) if you use `method="GET"`. Or you can send to `results` and redirect to expected address (`'/results/<url_postfix>'`). Or you can use JavaScript to modificate `action="/results"` when you click button in form.